# All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services

I have upgraded `gms:play-services-analytics` from `11.0.4` to `16.0.4`
and `firebase-messaging` from `11.0.4` to `17.1.0` but **lint** is giving this error

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.1.0, 16.2.0, 16.0.4, 16.0.3, 16.0.1, 16.0.0. Examples include `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0`
```

I gave a look into the `External libraries` i can see different versions of gms is being used here.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier-16.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-16.0.4
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl-16.0.4
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-16.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-16.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base-16.0.3
```

Similary

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-common-16.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-16.2.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop-16.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-17.1.0
```

i have only added the following two dependencies

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'`
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`

root level `build.gradle` contains

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

As mentioned in the blog 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

All firebase/gms libraries can now have a different versioning and the libraries mentioned above are imported by android itself.
Why i am getting this error ?

Comment: What versions of Android Studio, Gradle / Android Gradle plugin are you using?  Does updating to the latest of those fix the problem? What about updating google-services plugin to latest version as well?

Comment: @JustinHong Is it a known issue.I am using latest version of android studio and build-tools.It seem android is using these different version of the library internally and lint is throwing an issue for same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using a rather old build tools version. Updating to build tools 28.0.3 fixed the problem.